# Set a LIMIT to an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql, insert, limit, sql-insert

I have a table with a limit of 3 rows per user, so each user can only add 3 elements in the table.

I wrote something like:

```
INSERT INTO 'MyTable' ('ID', 'eMail', 'ISBN') 
VALUES ('333', 'a@d', '222') , ('433','e@r', '223')
```

but the problem is that I have no idea how to set the limit for the insertion. I just know that I cannot use `LIMIT` because it only works with a `SELECT` query.

Comment: I would probably just program that constraint in application code.

Comment: How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is there any single query that will handle `limit` and `insert` at once or not? I would rather count rows by each user id before inserting new rows for that user.

**For Example:**

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as CNT from `MyTable` GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

So the above query will return only the ID->respective row count of that ID, with this information you can easily filter out which user can have new row on your table and which should be discarded?

```
ID      CNT
333      2
899      1
443      2

INSERT INTO 'MyTable' ('ID', 'eMail', 'ISBN') VALUES ('333', 'a@d', '222') , ('899','e@r', '223'), ('443','f@r', '224')
```